# По какому принципу данное регулярное выражение выбирает идентификаторы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

У меня есть регулярное выражение, которые выбирает все слова или цифры, которые начинаются либо с буквы либо со знака _, просто отдельное число не выбирает:

```
([_A-z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```

Например она выберет текст:
a123, _123, abcd
Но не выберет:
123,1(все числа), 3abc(выберет только abc).
Вопрос вот в чем, зачем нам первое выражение [_A-z], если во втором выражении мы это продублировали, и почему если убрать его работать не будет?

Comment: Смысл шаблона в квадратных скобках, в том что под совпадение может попасть любой символ прописанный в них, причем порядок символов не важен. Пример `[ab][cd]` валидными будут `ac bc ad bd`, а в случае `[abcd]{2}` валидными будут `aa ab ac ad ba bb bc bd ca cb cc cd da db dc dd` . Следует, что если убрать первую часть шаблона, то слово может начинаться с цифры, буквы или символа нижнего подчеркивания

Comment: `[ooops`. Неверная у тебя регулярка.

Answer (score 0):

```
(                    # начало 1-ой группы (сохраняемая группа)
   [_A-z]            # нижнее подчёркивание и любой символ из интервала с A по z,
                     # здесь же скрыта потенциальная ошибка (всё будет работать, но логика неправильная - смотрите таблицу ascii),
                     # видимо хотели сделать заглавная буква или подчеркивание, а это записывается так: [_A-Z]
   [_a-zA-Z0-9]*     # нижнее подчёркивание, любая буква латинского алфавита или цифра 0 и более раз
)                    # конец 1-ой группы
```

Теперь ответ на прямой вопрос:

Первое выражение не включает в себя цифры и буквы в нижнем регистре и определяет, что совпадение должно начинаться с буквы в верхнем регистре или подчеркивания